# Java - freepascal communication

Tags: java, communication, freepascal

I have a problem with a communication between java and freepascal(lazarus) app. I use sockets. They connect properly. Everything is going smooth until I want to send something from one app to another. In java instead of "abc" i have random chars. Heres the code:

Java:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1025);  
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();  
InputStream is = client.getInputStream();  
byte bytesTest[] = new byte[10000];  
byte bytes[] = new byte[is.read(bytesTest)];  
is.read(bytes);  
String textReceived = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");  
System.out.println(textReceived);
```

FP:

```
connect(socket, socket_info, SizeOf(socket_info));  
S := 'abcd';  
res := UTF8Bytes(S);  
send(socket, res, sizeof(res), 0);  
send(socket, res, sizeof(res), 0);

function UTF8Bytes(const s: UTF8String): TArray;  
begin  
  SetLength(Result, Length(s)+1);  
  if Length(Result)>0 then  
    Move(s[1], Result[0], Length(s));  
  Result[high(Result)] := 0;  
end;
```

Comment: Try using Telnet as a client to your Java server to see if Java receives correctly from that. Then use Telnet as a server to your Pascal code to see if it receives correctly. TO determine whether the problem is with Java or Pascal

Comment: The java code should be good. With java client it works well. Probably the pascal part is the problem, but i dont know what to do with it..

Comment: Edited your code formatting. don't use `<code>` blocks, indent your code by 4 spaces (or use the button with the curly braces)

Comment: Did you check that your UT8Bytes function returns correct array of bytes? And that these are actually bytes, not ints?

Comment: @tulskiy UT8Bytes works good. I just converted it backwards and it gave me the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really knowing anything about Pascal (I used it last about 12 years ago), your UTF8Byte function looks quite suspicious.

```
function UTF8Bytes(const s: UTF8String): TArray;  
begin  
  SetLength(Result, Length(s)+1);  
  if Length(Result)>0 then  
    Move(s[1], Result[0], Length(s));  
  Result[high(Result)] := 0;  
end;
```

What a type is `TArray`, it is really an array of bytes?
Are you trying to add a 0 byte at the end? Why?

Additionally, what are you doing here?

```
S := 'abcd';
res := UTF8Bytes(S);
send(socket, res, sizeof(res), 0);
send(socket, res, sizeof(res), 0);
```

Is S of type UTF8String? And why send the same string twice?

Now for your Java side, it looks strange, too.

```
byte bytesTest[] = new byte[10000];
byte bytes[] = new byte[is.read(bytesTest)];
is.read(bytes);
```

First you read some number of bytes (up to 10000) into your `bytesTest` array, then you create a new array `bytes` with the length being the number of bytes you just have read. And then you try to read again (this time not counting how much you have) in your `bytes` array.

If this works with some other Java peer, I would like to see this.

---

The way to go would be to first send the length of your byte[], and then send this much bytes.
On the reading side, make sure you read the right number of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

On the pascal side, assuming 'TArray' is a byte arrray, you are not sending the contents of your buffer, you're sending it's address. Also, instead of specifying the length of the data, you're specifying size of a pointer. Try this:

```
send(socket, res[0], Length(res), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a network byte ordering issue?  I do not know much about FP, but a quick search on the topic turns up some conventions on this page:

http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/teams/core/docs/standards/FreePascal.EN.aspx

You may need to do host-to-network byte ordering before sending, and then network-to-host byte ordering when receiving using FP.